# Got stuck in using transpose

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I was attempting to extract data from other workbooks into a master workbook. All of these workbooks were saved in one folder. And I wanted to open other workbooks automatically not manually. The data that I need to extract are non adjacent cells, and I want the data extracted from each source workbook to be shown in rows in the master workbook (because I have a head line in row 1, so after extracting data from the first workbook and paste in row 2, the data extracted from the second workbook will be listed in row 3 and so on)

However, when I ran the macro I got stuck in Transpose.

Below is my code

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Dim wkbTarget As Workbook
    Dim erow As Single
    Dim Filepath As String
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim pasteRange As Range

    Filepath = "C:\xxxxx\"
    MyFile = Dir(Filepath)

    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        If MyFile = "Import Info.xlsm" Then GoTo NextFile    
        Set wkbTarget = Workbooks("Import Info.xlsm")

        Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filepath & MyFile)   
        Set copyRange = wkbSource.Sheets("sheet1").Range("c3,f6,f9,f12,f15,f19,f21,f27,f30,f33,f37,f41")
        Set pasteRange = wkbTarget.Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1")

        For Each cel In copyRange
            cel.Copy
            ecolumn = wkbTarget.Sheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Column
            wkbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1").Paste Destination:=wkbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, ecolumn).Address)
            pasteRange.Cells(1, ecolumn).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Next
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        wkbSource.Close

    NextFile:
        MyFile = Dir

    Loop

End Sub
```

What I have done so far:

1. I transposed the data I extracted from source workbooks but they were not shown in the master workbook as what I expected. All of them are in row 1
2. I don't have much experience in VBA and I feel like the code I wrote to copy non adjacent cells and transpose in the master workbook makes the loop much more complicated. But I don't know where I went wrong or how to fix that.

Please help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: You never increment the `row` argument in your pasterange.  If you want the information from each worksheet to be in it's own row, you should increment the `row` argument each time you read in a new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the destination range outside of the loop and offset it inside of the loops:

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
    Dim Filepath As String, MyFile As String
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook, wkbTarget As Workbook
    Dim copyRange As Range, cel As Range, pasteRange As Range

    Set wkbTarget = Workbooks("Import Info.xlsm")
    Set pasteRange = wkbTarget.Sheets("sheet1").Range("a2") ' start at row 2

    Filepath = "C:\xxxxx\"
    MyFile = Dir(Filepath)

    While MyFile > ""
        If MyFile = "Import Info.xlsm" Then GoTo NextFile    

        Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filepath & MyFile)   
        Set copyRange = wkbSource.Sheets("sheet1").Range("c3,f6,f9,f12,f15,f19,f21,f27,f30,f33,f37,f41")

        For Each cel In copyRange

            pasteRange.Value = cel.Value   ' "copy" the value

            Set pasteRange = pasteRange.Offset(, 1) ' move to the next column

        Next

        wkbSource.Close

        Set pasteRange = pasteRange.EntireRow.Resize(1,1) ' move back to the first cell in the row

        Set pasteRange = pasteRange.Offset(1) ' move to the cell bellow (next row)

    NextFile:
        MyFile = Dir

    Wend    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I want to make this function working in each source file. And I changed the "Set wkbTarget = Workbooks("Import Info.xlsm")" to "Set wkbTarget = ActiveWorkBook", however I can not change If MyFile="" to MyFile = ActiveWorkBook, I figured out why and tried to use "ThisWorkBook.Fullname" but it didn't work. Do you mind giving me some opinions? I really appreciate it!

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks all the same

Comment: `wkbTarget.Name` sometimes does not have the extension so `If Filepath  & MyFile = wkbTarget.Fullname Then GoTo NextFile`